# How to delete a file from the most recent commit in Git or revert the commit?

Tags: git

I would like to delete some files from a specific commit or revert the commit in Git. I accidentally added some files to my commit and I want to discard them before pushing my project to my remote repository.

I've been trying with `git revert` but it didn't work out.

Comment: It depends whether the problematic commit is the most recent commit. Is it?

Comment: Yes, it's the last commit I made. I just want to remove those files from that commit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/927358/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+file+last+commit

Answer (score 0):

If necessary (because of the revert) you might need to `reset --hard` back to the troublesome commit (thus erasing the revert commit). That, if needed, would be

```
git reset --hard @~1
```

You are now at the bad commit. Now simply

```
git reset @~1
```

You are now back where you were *before* forming the bad commit. You are ready to make the commit again, but correctly this time! Examine the situation with `git status`. Add files but not the ones you regret adding, and commit.

Comment: Glad it helped! Do not make a "thank you" comment. If this answer was "the right answer" for you, click the checkmark at its left so that it is filled in. That is called _accepting_ the answer and is an important part of the question and answer cycle; it marks the cycle as completed (and you get two points of reputation).